# How to do performance testing using Jmeter with the existing cucumber scenarios?

Tags: ruby, selenium, cucumber, jmeter

I am working on a project where the core application needs a harness to send messages which will process the message and feed to a portal web application. I am writing the automated testing for the portal application using cucumber/ruby/capybara.

I have never used Jmeter but through a colleague i just understand the basics of the Jmeter GUI tool. I have been asked me to use Jmeter as harness tool so that I can later extend the functionality to do performance testing as well. How can I do this ? How can i use Jmeter in my automated scripts using cucumber/ruby/selenium or capybara to do my testing ? 
I dont want to use GUI as the whole test case should be automated end to end, I have to figure out a way to integrate Jmeter functionality to do test data set up and then run my browser test to check whether the data exists.

i hope my question is clear, ask me if you are not. Hoping to get a solution as i dont think it is a uncommon question.

Note: i have seen the ruby-jmeter gem, i think it does partly what i need but it is actually a DSL to use jmeter in ruby.the problem with that is I have to stick the syntax of gem and have to figure all the options in gem. I have also read a blog that this can be done using Jmeter recording proxy and running the browser tests at the proxy which I am not sure how to do that. here is the link where this is mentioned:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cukes/4ZGkf3a234Y

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding of the problem, please go through the below links

- for recording the script using Jmeter:
  http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf
- for integrating selenium in Jmeter:

  There are actually 2 ways of achieving this:

  1. exporting all your selenium scripts as *.jar and copying it to /junit folder under /lib folder of Jmeter.
     Use JUnit Sampler to execute your test cases: 
     http://intensetesting.wordpress.com/2013/09/25/integrating-jmeter-with-selenium-code/
  2. use WebDeriver plugin for Jmeter and write your selenium test cases in Jmeter:
     http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverTutorial/

Also you can run Jmeter via command line.

Comment: HI thanks for ur suggestion. I am using ur command line option, I created the .jmx file in jmeter GUI with all the settings i need and i am running in non_GUI mode inside my cucumber step. the test plan runs successfully but i have a problem here, when the test plan is run in no_GUI mode , it opens a terminal showing the log . the control from my cucumber step is going to this terminal and doesnt come back. so is there a way i can execute the jmeter test plan in background when run on command  line? there is a gem in ruby, https://github.com/flood-io/ruby-jmeter which might be help for me.

Comment: Please try using the below mentioned command to Run Jmeter in background:    

**Windows:** start /B jmeter -n -t "*.jmx" -l "*.jtl"

**Linux:** ./jmeter -n -t "*.jmx" -l "*.jtl" &